# Sitecore Media Library upload error

Tags: sitecore

I am a newbie to Sitecore 6.4.

I tried to upload an image to Media Library/Images. However, the system always tells me "One or more files could not be uploaded. See the Log file for more details.".

The error message is "IOErrorEvent type="IOError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2038"

I've assigned all the permission to sitecore\Admin, default\Anonymous, extranet\Anonymous.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Are you uploading to the file system ("as file") or to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the log folder under my sitecore site. There is a file called WebDAV.log.*****.txt.

Inside the file, it said:

"WebDAV feature is supported for Internet Explorer browser only."

Then I switched to IE9, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a fix apparently from the Sitecore team that involves enabling "'Anonymous' authentication in IIS for ‘/sitecore/shell/Applications/FlashUpload’ and ‘/sitecore/shell/Applications/Media’."

From http://maesitus-sitecore.blogspot.com/2011/04/sitecore-media-upload-is-not-working.html